# How to accomplish page open/close effect from center? (like ipad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im designing a Wordpress based site for a client and was wondering if it is possible to have the pages load then open/close from the center like the iPad?

The site will essentially look like an iPad with icons inside of it that lead to the other wordpress pages. Is this effect possible?

Thanks

Comment: this is a website design question, right?  (not really iOS related, other that that's what you want to mimic) i think you're referring to the "springboard" effect, which is simply an animation of a static image to full screen while the rest of the application is loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely advise using css transitions otherwise it will be incredibly slow.
Just include some CSS and toggle the class.

```
.app{
    width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.0);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.app.opened{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z4bP7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html

Comment: jQuery Tools is terribly out of date (jQuery 1.4.2), full of bugs (IE 9), uses jQuery poorly (LOTS of manual markup required), and not supported well by its author or community.  Which is all beside the point because the OP is not asking about an Overlay.